# Recommending Movie with java

Tags: java

I'm in the process of making a program where a user can be recommended of some new movies based on the previous movies they have watched (stored in database). In this case I'm taking into account the genre of the past movie, which then is used for finding the new movies (with the similar genre). The issue I'm having now is implementing the algorithm, here is the code I have so far

*MovieWatchedDao.java*

```
public Movie recommendMovie(String username) throws DaoException {

        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;

        Movie m = null;
        String jsonStr = m.getGenre();
        String[] temp;
        String delimiter = ",";

        temp = jsonStr.split(delimiter);
        String genre = temp [0];
        String genre1 = temp [1];
        String genre2 = temp[2];

        try {
            String query = "SELECT * FROM MOVIES WHERE GENRE LIKE ? OR GENRE LIKE ? OR GENRE LIKE ? ";
            ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
            ps.setString(1, genre);
            ps.setString(2, genre1);
            ps.setString(3, genre2);
            ps.execute();

            System.out.println(query);
            System.out.println("Recommend movies");

        }catch (SQLException e)
        {
            throw new DaoException(e.getMessage());
        }

        return m;

    }
```

*server.java*

```
                    else if ("recommend".equals(command))
                    {
                        String username = tokens[1];
                        try {
                            Movie m = IMovieWatched.findMovieByUser(username);

                            //Get the genres
                            String jsonStr = m.getGenre();
//                          socketWriter.println(jsonStr);

                            String[] items = jsonStr.split(",");
                            List<String> itemList = Arrays.asList(items);
                            socketWriter.println(itemList);

                        }catch(DaoException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
```

The idea here is for the user to type **recommend tommy** and the algorithm will take the list of movies tommy have watched from the database and gather the genres of those movies. Then, returns back to the user 3 movies with similar genres.

Comment: Specify. What troubles do you have with implementing your class/interface/whatever?

Comment: It is quite complex to explain in words. The code I have there is to recommend movies based on the username stored in database (there I have a **watched** table where a username and movie ID  is stored). I also have a seperate table specifically for movies where all the movies data are stored.

Comment: I wanted to take the movie ID from the watched table for a certain user, lets say Tommy with movieID 55. Then I get the movie with ID 55 from the movies table and get the genres of that movie.

Comment: Lastly, I want to recommend Tommy with a list of movies that have similar genres to the one he has already watched

Comment: But haven't you got the recommended movies with your code? What else is there to add? Maybe you need to save the results to a variable inside/outside of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Well if I was doing this, I would take the list of movies tommy has watched, then go through the list by counting how many movies in each genre tommy has watched. Which ever movie genre he has watched the most, I would then go randomly pick 3 movies from the "database" of that genre. If the movie that was randomly picked is in his watched list, pick another random movie of that genre. When you have 3 movies picked out, return the movies back. There is multiple ways you can do this, I recommend looking up Netflix's algorithm for recommend movies for an idea.

Comment: Yes, thats my plan, but its very confusing to implement it

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to get much about a Users' movie *likes* or *dislikes* based from the viewing of one or even two specific movies. You can obviously only base your recommendations on what movie type or types were previously watched. The more information you have about your movies in database and the movies watched by the User, the more accurate your recommendations can be. You don't want to base all your recommendations just on Genre alone, there are many things to consider in what I feel is a matter of importance:

```
Genre
Genre Type 
Lead Actor
Year Created
Rating (Rotten Tomatoes Critics Consensus)
Director
Run Time
Watch time
Other cast members
Distributed by
```

As an example let's say the User watches the movie named **Top Gun** (with Tom Cruise). Here would be a possible Data List for this popular movie **before** and **after** the User watched it.

```
Data Field       Before              After
==========================================
Title            Top Gun             Top Gun
Genre            Action              
Genre Type       Military Drama               
Lead Actor       Tom Cruise          
Year Created     1986                
Rating           83%                 
Director         Tony Scott          
Run Time         110 Minutes         
Watch Time (In User Table)           105 Minutes
Other Members    Kelly McGillis,     
                 Tom Skerritt,       
                 Val Kilmer,         
                 Anthony Edwards     
Distributed by   Paramount Pictures  
Date Watched (In User Table Only)    April 10, 2019
Times Watched (In User Table Only)   1
```

**Data Fields** are database Movies table fields, **Before** is the data in the Movies table, and **After** would be related fields in the database Users table. In the example above we can clearly see that the User watched the movie named "Top Gun" on April 10, 2019 and basically watched it right through to the credits which means he/she most likely enjoyed the movie. If **Watch Time = Run Time** then there is a probability that the User walked away from the media device playing the movie or fell asleep during the movie. If the table shows the movie was watched twice then the probability can be reduced by comparing the Watch Time and can show a more likely outcome that the User enjoyed the movie.

Everyone has different tastes in the movies they would enjoy and the more movies they watch and the more data you can keep track of then obviously the more accurate your recommendations will be.

At this particular moment you want to keep this simple and merely base your recommendations on Genre alone. To start with, you will need to maintain a database table of Users which stores the User Name and the Movie Names they watch which are also contained within your database within a Movies table:

Users Table:

```
RowID        Long (Unique - AutoIncrement)
UserName     Text
UserID       Text
MovieName    Text
ReleaseDate  Date
DateWatched  Date
TimeStarted  Long
TimeEnded    Long
```

You now need to query the User within database and retrieve all movies he/she watched:

```
String sql = "SELECT DISTINCT MovieName From UsersTable WHERE UserName = ?;"
```

Place the ResultSet into an String Array (watchedMovies[]). Now query the Movies table in database to retrieve all the different Genre's for those watched movies by the User:

```
// This is just a quick example....
StringBuilder criteria = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < watchedMovies.length; i++) {
    criteria.append("MovieName = '").append(watchedMovies[i]).append("'");
    if (i != (watchedMovies.length - 1)) {
        criteria.append(" OR ");
    }
}

sql = "SELECT Genre FROM MoviesTable WHERE " + criteria.toString() + ";"
```

Again, place all the different Genre's from the above query ResultSet into a String Array (watchedGenres[]). **Find the Genre that is watched the most.** Use the following method to get this from a String Array:

```
public static String mostFrequentElementInArray(String[] arr) {
    // Method returns the String element with highest frequency 

    // Create HashMap to store string elements and thier frequency 
    HashMap<String, Integer> hs = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); 

    // Iterate through array of strings 
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
        // If word already exist in HashMap then increase it's count by 1 
        if (hs.containsKey(arr[i])) { 
            hs.put(arr[i], hs.get(arr[i]) + 1); 
        } 
        // Otherwise add String element to HashMap 
        else { 
            hs.put(arr[i], 1); 
        } 
    } 

    // Create set to iterate over HashMap 
    Set<Map.Entry<String, Integer> > set = hs.entrySet(); 
    String key = ""; 
    int value = 0; 

    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> me : set) { 
        // Check for String having highest frequency 
        if (me.getValue() > value) { 
            value = me.getValue(); 
            key = me.getKey(); 
        } 
    } 

    // Return String having highest frequency 
    return key; 
}
```

And to use this method:

```
String recommendedGenre = mostFrequentElementInArray(watchedGenres);
```

Now you can query the database Movies table for all (or some of) the movies of that particular Genre:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM MoviesTable WHERE Genre = '" + recommendedGenre + "';";
```

How accurate the recommendation you want depends upon what type of movie data you store and what you use within your **WHERE** clause criteria, for example:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM MoviesTable WHERE Genre = '" + recommendedGenre + "' AND GenreType = 'Military Drama';";
```

If this fails to produce the number of desired results then step it down to:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM MoviesTable WHERE Genre = '" + recommendedGenre + "';";
```

Place the ResultSet into a String Array and display it to the User. You can do this with most fields within your Movies table if you like by simply adding the **AND** statement within your **WHERE** clause. The more criteria you use within your **WHERE** clause the more accurate your Movie Recommendation will be.

The more movies the User watches the more the database learns about what the User likes. Eventually it can be determined that the User only watches movies with Tom Cruise in them (for some unknown reason). :)